# .sibling() and .next() not working in IE

Tags: jquery

I could not understand why this code is working in FF but not in IE.

```
<table id="knowledgeTreeTable" >
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="">Who are the services being provided for?</th>
      <td class="">Text</td>
      <input id="answerText0_Old" class="oldAns" type="hidden" value="Named Insured" />
      <input type="hidden" value="Who are the services being provided for?" />
      <input type="hidden" value="1014"/>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

$("#knowledgeTreeTable td").each(function() {
    alert($jq11(this).next().val());
    $(this).html("Text");
});
```

FF does show text bit IE shows id blank. I used siblings() FF shows text but IE print undefined. Any idea?

Comment: What version of jQuery and IE?  And your HTML is invalid. Your inputs need to be within a table cell.

Comment: That HTML is invalid. You should fix it first and then complain that tool X doesn't work; it's meant to work when given valid HTML.

Comment: Is that valid HTML? You have inputs within a `<tr>` but not within a `<td>`

Comment: Those two _orphan_ inputs are being rendered outside the table, because they're not within a td or a th. A quick inspection in the page source will show you that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a valid HTML, input are not allowed as `TR` childs. Probably this is the reason because it works on random basis across browsers.

Different browsers implement a different strategy in cases like this. I'd say it is irrelevant which strategy is "correct", you should fix your HTML to make it valid.